# warning C4715: not all control paths return a value c++ - cant pass a test

Tags: c++, recursion, return

I'm having an issue with this code:

The problem is I'm constantly getting warning C4715 despite the fact .exe is running correctly and it gives correct answer to a problem I'm trying to resolve. The warning makes it impossible to pass the task inside the app. Please give me a clue why 'return' used by me in the if sentences doesn't work.

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>


    std::pair<int, int> solve(int a, int b) {
    
        if (a == 0 || b == 0) {
            std::pair <int, int> kek(a, b);
            return kek;
    
        }
        else if (a >= 2 * b) {
            a = (a - (2 * b));
            solve(a, b);
        }
        else if (b >= 2 * a) {
            b = (b - (2 * a));
            solve(a, b);
        }
        else {
            std::pair <int, int> kek(a, b);
            return kek;
        }
        
    }
    
    int main() {
        bool result{ solve(22, 5) == std::make_pair(0,1) };
        std::cout << result;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `solve(a, b);` maybe you wanted to return this? Not returning a value from a non-void function is undefined behavior.

Comment: ***despite the fact .exe is running correctly*** One of the worst things about undefined behavior is when it appears to work even though its totally broken.

Comment: Unrelated: instead of `kek` stuff, you can simply write `return {a, b};`.

Comment: Seems a common newbie misunderstanding, recursive tail calls still need to return from the calling function. Try `return solve(a, b);`

Comment: If you can't return at the end of the routine for some reason, you can end the routine with a `throw std::runtime_error("oopsies");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `solve` function won't execute `return` statement if `a == 0 || b == 0` is not true and either one of `a >= 2 * b` or `b >= 2 * a` is true.

It seems that the two `solve(a, b);` in the `solve` function should be `return solve(a, b);`.