# Warning C4715 not all control paths return a value - Cant find out what may be wrong in the code

Tags: c++

My problem is that I'm getting the warning C4715 again and I have no clue why...

I'm aware of possible undefined beahviour and already checked definitions. Please help a newbie in need.

#edit - of course im missing 'algorithm' but that doesnt solve problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int solve(std::vector<int> v) {    
    for (int i = 0; i < v.capacity(); i++) {
        auto result1 = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), -v[i]);
        if (result1 != v.end())
            std::cout << "v contains the opposite of: " << v[i] << '\n';
        else {
            std::cout << "v doesnt have match to: " << v[i] << '\n';
            return v[i];
        }
    }
}


int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{ {1,-1,2,-2,3} };
    std::cout << solve(v);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4715?view=vs-2019 ?

Comment: @jtbandes Yes. Somehow I'm still missing in which case its possible to omit the return.

Comment: if the `for` loop ends, you have no return

Comment: How many for loop iterations run if `v` has no capacity?

Comment: **Always**, when you get an error message, include it in full in your question.

Comment: Side note: `capacity`'s not that useful a-thing to test here. Capacity is a measure of how many things can be in the `vector` without needing to be resized. For a count of how many things are in the `vector` use `size`

Comment: Please, do not post the same question [warning C4715: not all control paths return a value c++ - cant pass a test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63208314/warning-c4715-not-all-control-paths-return-a-value-c-cant-pass-a-test).

Answer (score 0):

" if the for loop ends, you have no return " - credit to @Berto99

Comment: Is not it better to let Berto99 know, that his/her suggestion worked for you and ask him/her to write it as an answer, which you might then accept, resp. upvote?